# Fitting function with multiple outputs Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have a function of the form (y1,y2) = x*(a1,a2)+(b,b), where x, y1 and y2 are measured values and a1,a2 and b are the parameters I fit for. How can I do this in python? I tried using curve_fit like this:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    y = y + [[1.2*x[i]+2,-2.2*x[i]+2]]
y = np.array(y)

def f(x,a,b,c):
    return np.transpose(np.array([a*x+c,b*x+c]))

curve_fit(f,x,y)
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because your function hast to return the value for `y` as a `float` and not as `list`. With your code the `y` variable is an array of lists and not an array of floats.
You have to separate `y1` and `y2` and call `curve_fit` for each `y`.

With the following code you can get the `curve_fit` for `y1` and `y2` independently for the equation (y1,y2) = x*(a1,a2)+(b,b):

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y1 = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    y1.append(1.2*x[i]+2)
y1 = np.array(y1)

y2 = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    y2.append(-2.2*x[i]+2)
y2 = np.array(y2)
```

To ensure that the parameter `b` is the same for both `y`, you can define two separate functions replacing `b` in the second one with the result of `curve_fit` from the first one:

```
def f1(x,a,b):
    return a*x+b

def f2(x,a):
    return a*x+curve_fit(f1,x,y1)[0][1]  # here replace b for curve_fit(f1,x,y1)[0][1]
```

output:

```
>>> print(curve_fit(f1,x,y1))  # results for y1 ([a1, b])

(array([1.2, 2. ]), array([[ 1.31476816e-31, -3.94430449e-31],
       [-3.94430449e-31,  1.44624498e-30]]))

>>> print(curve_fit(f2,x,y2))  # results for y2 ([a2])

(array([-2.2]), array([[5.37859713e-33]]))
```

Note: You can run the script 2 times exchanging the functions (take the 2nd eq. first and then  the first one) and see if the value of `b2` is similar to `b1` the first time you ran the script. If both are similar you can calculate the mean (`(b1+b2)/2`) and it would be your optimized `b`. If both values of `b` are not similar it means either there is no value for `b` in R (real numbers) or there are multiple values for `b` that satisfy both equations.

Comment: But this doesn't do what I want. I need the parameter c to be the same in both cases. If I separate it like that, that is not guaranteed. It worked in the simple example above, but that is not true in general.

Comment: @BillKet To ensure that the parameter ```b``` is the same for both ```y```, you can define two separate functions replacing ```b``` in the second one with the result of ```curve_fit``` from the first one. I've edited the code to show this

Comment: I am not sure. If the first equation is y1.append(1.2*x[i]+1.9) and the second one is y2.append(-2.2*x[i]+2) I am getting some weird results. Even if b is expected to be the same in both cases, in practice (from measurement) that is not always the case due to the noise. In this case I am getting b=1.9 for the first one and b=4e-5, so this doesn't enforce b to be the same for both. I would expect the fit value of b to be common to both and probably between 1.9 and 2.

Comment: how are you getting ```b=4e-5``` for the second function if it only gets ```x, a``` as input and returns only the value for ```a``` as output. The parameter ```b``` should be the one you got from the first ```curve_fit```

Comment: Sorry! My bad, that was the loss. So what is the value of b then? Is it 1.9 in both cases? That is clearly not right. I want b to be optimized simultaneously for both equations. I don't want to fix it to the first one, and assume it is the same for the second one.

Comment: you can run the script 2 times exchanging the functions (take the 2nd eq. first and then  the first one) and see if the value of ```b2``` is similar to ```b1``` the first time you ran the script. If both are similar you can calculate the mean (```(b1+b2)/2```) and it would be your optimized ```b```. If both values of ```b``` are not similar it means either there is no value for ```b``` in R (real numbers) or there are multiple values for ```b``` that satisfy both equation.

Comment: That won't work... It might work for the simple case of a linear function, but not in general. Also the error propagation won't be correct if I calculate b for each fit and then take the average, especially if y has more entries not just 2. Your solution might work (approximately) for 2 entries and a linear relationship, but it is definitely not a solution. Even in this simple case I doubt the error propagation would do well.